# Parameter passing to webapp on doGet(e)

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to figure out how parameters in URL are passed to `doGet()` function.
I tried to do

`https://script.google.com/a/macros/[my domain].com/s/[some random string generated by GAS]` followed by `"&variable=data"`

but it only gave me this error:
*"Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist."*

FYI, `https://script.google.com/a/macros/[my domain].com/s/[some random string generated by GAS]` works well without `"&variable=data".`

Comment: how did you publish it?

Comment: sorry for my momentary wrong answer, was for another post ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add GET parameters to the end of a URL, you need to use a `?`.

So your URL should look something like this

```
http://script.[.......]/exec?variable=data&otherVariable=otherData
```

Also, be sure you publish your app to get this functionality. File > Manage Versions. Publish > Publish as Web App...

Comment: You can also add these parameters if you're using the "dev" version of the script. (That's the "test your latest code" option from the Publish interface). That would look like this `http://script.[...]/dev?variable=data`

Comment: How do you access those parameter values in your script?