# Pass e.parameter to array with doPost method

Tags: php, javascript, variables, google-apps-script, dopostback

Can you pass parameters through DoPost method? I am trying to pass e.parmaters to my array. All I see in return is empty brackets without the value of the parameter I want to push.

Code:

```
function doPost(e) {
    createProcess(e);
    createStep();
}

function createProcess(e) {
    var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication(); //get the current UI application
    process = [];
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AuCblud0Ss7BdHA1bXZgmjYXA0liY0IyekhUQm5vWG02MVE").getActiveSheet(    ); //opens spreadsheet 
    var row = sheet.getLastRow(); //grabs current row
    process.push(createStep([e.parameter.DivHeadEmail,]));
    process.push(createStep([e.parameter.Director]));
    saveProcess(process,sheet,row);
}

function createStep(approvers) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AuCblud0Ss7BdHA1bXZjYXhkhkA0Y0IyekhUQm5vWG02MVE").getActiveSheet();
    var row = sheet.getLastRow(); 
    var  step = new Object();
    step['numberOfApprovers'] = approvers.length;
    step['approvers'] = approvers.slice(1);
    step['status'] =  "approved" ;
    return step;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are able to pass parameters to doPost(e) just as [you can with doGet(e)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914955/how-to-call-google-apps-script-from-web-page/14915184#14915184).

You can check what parameters are being passed to your doPost(e) method by using this inside of it.

```
var parameters = "";
for (var i in e.parameter) {
  parameters += "e.parameter."+i+" = "+e.parameter[i];
}
Logger.log(parameters);
```

Comment: how do I check the log? I pasted the code inside my doPost and I'm posting it back to a spreadsheet. Can I view this throgh a UIAPP or something?

Comment: You should be able to open the script editor where this doPost() method is listed, then make a POST request (invoke the script), and click View > Logs.

Comment: This is what I get when I run the depost method..TypeError: Cannot read property "parameter" from undefined

Comment: I have gotton used to just using Utilities.jsonStringify(e) as the Logger step. Lazy but functional.

Comment: @lockdown277, you shouldn't be running the doPost method. You should make a POST request as you normally would. Then go back and check the logs.

Comment: @Phil Bozak .. Im sorry Phil...Im a nub. I wouldn't even begin to know how to make a Post request. I have been dealing with this for a couple of weeks now. I am trying to make a workflow. When someone submits a form, the DoGet sends values to sendEmail_ function via Callback (I guess). SendEmail_ function sets values to spreadsheet and sends the approver an email with e.parm values. At the point when approver selects the approve button is when DoPost function is called. I have an arra y that is saved to my spreadsheet I want my Dopost to change values in array from "pending" to "approved".

Comment: I just meant to test the logging by running this code as you normally would.