# Opening template html in a new window from UiApp Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a UiApp script that display images in flextable; I have assigned mousedown handler to the images so that when it is clicked I want it to open a templated HTML page (in a new window). I wrote the following code; it gets executed but it doesnt return anything.
What should I do to get the Item Detail page containing the image loaded from the imageurl assigned to be opened in a new window?

Here's my script and html code:

```
  var page = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Item Detail");
  var image = productDetails[i].imageurl;   
  page.imageurl = image;
  Logger.log(productDetails[i].imageurl);
  return page.evaluate();

<img src=<?=imageurl ?> alt="click for more info" height="100%" width="100%">
```

Comment: if this is not possible. is there a way to launch a new UiApp in a new window? I'm making a uiapp that displays a list of images of items, when the image is clicked, i want to open a new window that will give a more detailed description of the image. First I thought of doing this through template HTML, but if this is not possible what about creating a new UiApp that will pop up in a new window? is this possible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So suppose you want to make a clickable image. And you want this image to open in a new window when you click on it.

```
var anchor = app.createAnchor("<img src='URL_TO_IMAGE' />",
                          true,
                          ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()+"?detailPage="+SOME_ID)
              .setTarget("_blank");
```

Then when you click on that link, your script will be opened in another window. And also, a GET parameter will be passed along with it. So in your doGet(e) function, you could handle whether to display the main UiApp or an Html detail page.

```
function doGet(e) {
  if (e.parameter.detailPage) {
    //show the detail page
  } else {
    //show the normal UiApp
  }
}
```

Read the top part of [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914955/how-to-call-google-apps-script-from-web-page/14915184#14915184) to get a better idea of how GET parameters work with GAS.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to surround the `<img>` with a `<a>` tag.

```
<a href="URL_TO_OPEN_IN_NEW_WINDOW" target="_blank"><img ... ></a>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I think maybe I didnt make my question very clear. I want to have the whole html open in a new window, not have a link to open in a new window.