# HtmlService createTemplateFromFile: how to display template on a JQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script

I explain my problem.
I have a GoogleAppsScript that generates an html page from the command

`return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('page_id').evaluate();`

where page_id is a HTML page in the script.

Externally, I want to display the result in a jQuery dialog using ColorBox:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".class").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
});
```

In php page, i have `<a href="url" class="class">click</a>`

where `url` is the url of Google Apps Script Web Application's depoly. The Google Apps Script work correctly, but the HTML page created with HtmlService is not displayed correctly in the dialog.

Here is the page create from HtmlService:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <? var path = "url_to_redirect" ?>
  <p>Document created! <a href="<?= path ?>">Click to view the document</a>

 </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: what do you mean by "not displayed correctly"? what happens? is there any error?

Comment: in the dialog, i see a blank page and not the html created by HtmlService

Answer (score 1):

There is an ["issue" that should explain everything you need to know](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=852). Basically, it's a security issue. Google doesn't want Apps Scripts to be loaded in an iframe (unless you're on Google Sites, in which case, it's perfectly fine).

You could alternatively use [JSONP to load Apps Script data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914955/how-to-call-google-apps-script-from-web-page/14915184#14915184) into your site.

Comment: In my external page, I have a form with an input box. When I insert a value in that, when i click a button I call, in the action attribute, the GAS url (with parameters). 

I give a class to the button and this class is used into the jQuery code in order to open a dialog and in that dialog the script works. Now, can I substitute the HtmlService with another Service in order to display the script result?