# Using Google Apps Script as a private API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-authentication

If I publish a Google Apps Script as a public website, I can use it like any other API, sending XHR request to the Google service is not a problem (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14915184/840315):

Client:

```
var SCRIPT_URL = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/ID/exec";
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON(SCRIPT_URL+"?callback=?",
              {method:"populate_list"},
              function (data) { 
                alert(JSON.stringify(data)); 
              });
});
```

My problem with this, is the public part. Can I do the same with Google authentication? Or should I create an API Key to authenticate and check it every time a request is processed?

```
function doGet(e) {
  if (e.parameter.apikey!="LONG_API_KEY_LIKE_THING") {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('invalidrequest')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: If you are using API key, you cannot access the users private data. For this you have to follow any one flow from this link : https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Comment: You mean a public web application can't access the gDrive and other user data?

Comment: Edit: I think you misunderstood me, I am not talking about Google's API KEY, I am hosting the GAS as a public application, It can do anything (as long as I understand), but I don't want it to be public, all I want is to be able to send ajax requests to my google script.